# How can we Differentiate Cauchy's Formula for Repeated Integrals?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, functional-equations

[Cauchy's formula for repeated integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) tells us that the $n$'th repeated integral of a function $f$, evaluated from $a$ to $x$, can be expressed as a single integral:

$$f^{(-n)}(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$

Using the exponent function as an example:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{t}dt = e^{x}$$

How would one go about deriving $f(x)=e^{x}$, given its identity equation:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$

In other words, how can one **isolate** and solve for $f$ in the following equation:

$$e^{x}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$

rather than plugging in $f(t)=e^{t}$, and showing that it is a valid solution?

I have tried the following simple steps, and I don't know how to proceed:

1. Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(e^{x})=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt\right)$$

2)

$$e^{x}=\lim_{a \to -\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left.(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\right|_{t=a}^{t=x}$$

3. We now lose $f(x)$ as it is being multiplied by $(x-x)^{n-1}$ i.e., $0$

$$e^{x}=\lim_{a \to -\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left((x-x)^{n-1}f(x) - (x-a)^{n-1}f(a)\right)$$

4)

$$\lim_{a \to -\infty}f(a)\frac{-(x-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = e^{x}$$

This equation only seems to give us an expression for one point $f(a)$ as $a\rightarrow-\infty
$

To summarise, can we somehow find an expression for $f(x)$ from $e^{x}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$

Thank you!

Comment: First, it seems that you made a mistake when differentiating the integral. Assuming that $f$ is nice (or more precisely, $x^kf(x)\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$ for any $k\geq 0$) and writing $$F(u,v):=\int_{-\infty}^{u}\frac{(v-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ the chain rule gives $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x,x)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}=0+\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

That's very interesting! I did not know that you could treat the two $x$'s (one in the integral limit and the other inside the integral) as separate variables, $u$ & $v$, as you did.

So if we follow this process that should give us:  $$\frac{\text{d}^{n+1}}{\text{d}x^{n+1}}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt\right) = \lim_{a \to -\infty} (f(x) - f(a)) = f(x)$$
Given the assumption that $\lim_{a \to -\infty} f(a) = 0$.

Is there any other way to invert the equation to solve for $f$ ?

Comment: Glad it helped. This is part of a more general technique called the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), and is a versatile tool for dealing the case when both the domain of integration and integrand are functions of a variable. Also, this computation is precisely the basis of the Cauchy's formula (as demonstrated in the Wikipedia link). As for the equality in your comment, I would say that it is true if $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n+1}}$ is replaced by $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n}}$.

Comment: Also, since the integral transform $$f\mapsto\int_{a}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ is precisely an $n$-fold antiderivative, inverting this transform literally corresponds to taking $n$-fold differentiation as you did. It is hard for me to envision an approach that avoids this idea.

Comment: @SangchulLee That's true.

So to solve for $f$, given:
 $$g(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$
We get:
 $$\frac{\text{d}^{n+1}}{\text{d}x^{n+1}}g(x) = f(x)$$
Assuming niceness, does that mean we can use Cauchy's formula once more to get:$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(-n-2)!}\int_{-\infty}^{x} (x-t)^{-n-2}g(t)dt $$

Which seems to be the only forseeable way to invert it?

Comment: @SangchulLee PS - I'll read up on the Leibniz Integral rule Thank you for the help! Have a good one!